# Xamarin app running on mode release

Tags: android, xamarin

I developing app with `Visual Studio for Community` in specific `Android`, but when I run my app in `Debug mode` no problem, but I trying run in `Release mode` when my app try connect to my web server in console shows `mView == null` and this message `sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`, I don't know why, please help.

Comment: do you have internet permissions enabled in your manifest?

Comment: Wow, in mode debug these permissions are enabled, but in release no, I newbie in this, sorry!

Comment: yes, it does it by default in Debug